# Java8 Glob PathMatcher with size filter

Tags: java

My goal is to create a FileScanner with the functionality of globs and add some custom filter functions (like min or max filesize).

My first try was:

```
    final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.java");
    Path path2 = Paths.get("c:/dummy");
    try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path2)) {
        stream.filter(pathMatcher::matches).forEach(FileProcessor::processFile);
    }
```

This worked fine in order to find only *.java files within c:\dummy directory. But what do I need to do in order so find only *.java files smaller than 1000 bytes?

My attempt was:

```
    PathMatcher myMatcher = path -> {
        // Do size comparision ...
        return true;
    };

    Path path = Paths.get("c:/dummy");
    try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path)) {
        stream.filter(myMatcher::matches).forEach(FileProcessor::processFile);
    }
```

But with this solution I don't have the globs anymore.

The last try was:

Path path3 = Paths.get("c:/dummy");
        final PathMatcher pathMatcher2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.java");

```
    Files.walkFileTree(path3, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            if (pathMatcher2.matches(path)) {
                // Do size comparison
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

The last one worked, but it doesn't look so nice and feels a little bit complicated with the SimpleFileVisitor Object.

Anyone a good idea how to solve that issue?

Greetings,
Hauke

Comment: `Files.list()` will not walk in depth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the attributes of the file name you want to check, you can use `Files.find()` instead:

```
// Note that you can use a `PathMatcher` for the name instead if you want
final BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> filter =
    (path, attrs) -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".java") && attrs.size() <= 1000L;

try (
    final Stream<Path> = Files.find(baseDir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, filter);
) {
    // process the stream
}
```

You can also use `Files.walk()`; however, the advantage of `Files.find()` is that it will automatically retrieve the attributes for you: with `Files.walk()` this has to be done manually.

Comment: little correction: you have to call "toString" after "getFileName()" because getFileName return a Path object and then endsWith has a different meaning

Comment: @Hauke oops... Yes, I always forget about that one